# How to group properties of a specific type in a region with ReSharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-9.1

I want to use the ReSharper File Layout tool to autoarange my class. With the default pattern it already works with most regions. Since I'm using Mvvm I use ICommands and Handlers. I want to group all commands in a own region like

```
#region Commands

public ICommand NavigateToSettingsView { get { return new RelayCommand(OnNavigateToSettingsView); } }
public ICommand NavigateToHistoryView { get { return new RelayCommand(OnNavigateToHistoryView); } }

#endregion
```

How can I tell ReSharper that it will group properties of the type ICommand into one region? It doesn't work with the option "Implements".

This is the last setting I tried:

```
<Region Name="Commands" Priority="150">
      <Entry DisplayName="Commands" Priority="150">
        <Entry.Match>
          <ImplementsInterface Immediate="True" Name="ICommand" />
        </Entry.Match>
      </Entry>
    </Region>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JetBrains support there is no way to do it!
But maybe they will add that to the coming Resharper 9.2 release.