# How to configure Resharper File Layout to sort members inside existing Regions?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-2016

I have been able to successfully configure my c# File Layout to sort members the way I want them to with the exception of members ***inside*** of existing regions.

Is it possible to make this configuration?  I think this question: [How to group properties of a specific type in a region with ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878293/how-to-group-properties-of-a-specific-type-in-a-region-with-resharper) is almost the same question and it appears that it wasn't possible then (for an older version of Resharper).

Can it be done in Resharper 2016? And if so, how?

[image]

Comment: Your pattern does not show any regions...

Answer (score 0):

When you drag a region from the toolbox on the right, you will be able to drop members into it.

And within those regions, the member order will be preserved as you set it.

If you want more granular sorting then you might either have to create more member types (fields, private fields, static fields, readonly static private fields etc), or use the ordering in the MISC tool box...